# Adobe Flex/AIR iOS App - How to pass arguments into app?

Tags: ios, apache-flex, air, flash-builder

I am able to successfully open my app with the link `example://abc`.

However I need to capture the `abc` arguments at the end of the URI.

This is the code for the app

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" applicationDPI="240"
           creationComplete="creationComplete(event)">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;

            protected function creationComplete(event:FlexEvent):void
            {
                NativeApplication.nativeApplication.addEventListener(BrowserInvokeEvent.BROWSER_INVOKE, onInvokeEvent);
            }

            private function onInvokeEvent(e:BrowserInvokeEvent):void 
            { 
                var arguments:Array = e.arguments; 

                testLabel.text = "Args passed" //This never happens
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:Label id="testLabel" x="56" y="163" text="Testing invocation"/>

</s:Application>
```

I have also made sure to make these changes to the app.xml file:

```
<allowBrowserInvocation>true</allowBrowserInvocation>

<iPhone>
    <InfoAdditions><![CDATA[
        <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key> 
            <array> 
                <dict> 
                     <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key> 
                    <array> 
                        <string>example</string> 
                    </array> 
                    <key>CFBundleURLName</key> 
                    <string>com.example.app</string> 
                </dict> 
            </array>
    ]]></InfoAdditions>
</iPhone>
```

What changes would I need to make to capture the parameters for this app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because I was launching the app from another application (Calendar) I needed to use the InvokeEvent rather than the BrowserInvokeEvent.